# Dynamically define model attributes / database fields in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, python-class

I would like to define a Django Model looking like this:

```py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    object_id_1 = models.UUIDField()
    content_type_1 = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id_2 = models.UUIDField()
    content_type_3 = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id_3 = models.UUIDField()
    content_type_3 = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    # etc.
    d1 = GenericForeignKey("content_type_1", "object_id_1")
    d2 = GenericForeignKey("content_type_2", "object_id_2")
    d3 = GenericForeignKey("content_type_3", "object_id_3")
    # etc.
```

Obviously, the more dimensions (`d` stands for "*dimension*") I add, the messier it gets: this isn't very DRY, all the more since I've removed the many fields options in this example.

Is there a way to dynamically define these model attributes, for instance in a `for` loop, without using `eval`? If not, what would be the cleanest and safest way to resort to `eval` here?

I've found a very similar Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029479/django-dynamically-defining-model-fields) but it is more specific and it hasn't got any generic answer.

Comment: If you have N number of these relations, why don't you just create another model with a foreign key to this and the generic foreign key to the other models? Also no need for eval, you could make use of `type` to dynamically create classes if you need to.

Comment: Could you please illustrate what you have in mind? I’m not sure to get it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### My solution

I'm not entirely satisfied with this piece of code because it means relying on [undocumented
internals](https://github.com/django/django/blob/123b1d3fcf79f091573c40be6da7113a6ef35b62/django/db/models/base.py#L369) which have no stability guarantee whatsoever, but this is what I've finally done, for future readers:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    NB_DIMENSIONS = N
    pass

# outside of the class
for i in range(1, Foo.NB_DIMENSIONS + 1):
    Foo.add_to_class(f"object_id_{i}", models.UUIDField())
    Foo.add_to_class(f"content_type_{i}", models.ForeignKey(ContentType))
    Foo.add_to_class(f"d{i}", GenericForeignKey(f"content_type_{i}", f"object_id_{i}"))
```

Here, I'm indirectly using the Managers `contribute_to_class` hook as described [in this old Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357528/explanation-of-contribute-to-class). It is mentioned [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DevModelCreation) as well. One should pay attention to the fact that this method is an undocumented, private, internal API. Django does not provide backwards-compatibility guarantees for it, and if you make use of it you accept the risk that it might change or break at any time.

### Alternative 1

The following code seems to work as well, but note that it's [a bad idea to modify `locals`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997184/why-is-it-bad-idea-to-modify-locals-in-python) in Python:

```py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    NB_DIMENSIONS = N
    for i in range(1, NB_DIMENSIONS + 1):
        locals()[f"object_id_{i}"] = models.UUIDField()
        locals()[f"content_type_{i}"] = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
        locals()[f"d{i}"] = GenericForeignKey(f"content_type_{i}", f"object_id_{i}")
```

Let me insist on this: using `locals()` may be a bad idea for various reasons, even if it seems more readable.

### Alternative 2

As suggested by @Abdul Aziz Barkat above, it should be possible be to create a intermediate class with `type()` (cf. this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112816/dynamically-creating-django-models-with-type)). This has its downsides: that implies one more class to manage and I believe it's harder to understand and to maintain for less experienced developers.